# Does it ever make sense to use logical variables to represent dummy variables in regression analysis in R?

Tags: r, regression

As far as I know, R treats logical variables as factor variables with two levels during regression analysis. This seems to work well in most cases but yields unexpected results in some cases (see below). So I was wondering: Is it ever beneficial to code dummy variables as logical variables in R rather than as numeric variables?

When the logical variable is included as a main effect, R detects the collinearity of its two factor levels and drops the `FALSE` level. However, when only the interaction is present, R fails to detect the collinearity and estimates two coefficients where I would have expected only one:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# create dataset
dat <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(vs = as.logical(vs))

# regression with main effects
lm(mpg ~ vs + disp + vs:disp, data = dat)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ vs + disp + vs:disp, data = dat)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)       vsTRUE         disp  vsTRUE:disp  
#>    25.63755      8.39771     -0.02937     -0.04219

# regression without main effects
lm(mpg ~ vs:disp, data = dat)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ vs:disp, data = dat)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>  (Intercept)  vsFALSE:disp   vsTRUE:disp  
#>     30.05647      -0.04228      -0.04591
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Is there any way to make sense of this behavior or should dummy variables just be represented as numeric variables in R?

Comment: Good questions.  I find the rules/logic of the `:` operator (and what/when terms are dropped) rather obscure.